# Importing XML file into SQL Server is too slow

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

the task I want to achieve is import XML file into SQL Server. Once prepare the empty table I would load the entire xml file and fill that table. Googling I found that SQL Bulk Insert is suitable so I tested the following code which runs fine:

```
INSERT INTO Products (sku, product_desc)
SELECT X.product.query('SKU').value('.', 'INT'),
       X.product.query('Desc').value('.', 'VARCHAR(30)')
FROM (
SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'C:\Products.xml',
    SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
    ) AS T(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Products/Product') AS X(product);
```

My XML file count around 1860 nodes, (30kb), quite small but the above procedure takes over 5 minutes to import the whole file. Is there any chance to spee up this process?
I've also read that SQL Server 2008 have a bug which affect the bulk object.
Any hints?

Comment: You are better off parsing the XML in C# or another language and importing it through an application.

Comment: Yeah you're right. First attempt was importing the xml using C# but I thought that Bulk procedures of SQL Server were more reliable

Comment: Well, XML and relational databases... not normally a good fit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this - I imported a file with 4'096 records from disk in just 53 seconds (on a regular average desktop machine - no high-perf server):

```
-- declare XML variable
DECLARE @InputXML XML

-- import file from disk
SELECT @InputXML = CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\temp\Products.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)

-- parse XML using XQuery and insert into the table    
INSERT INTO dbo.Products (sku, product_desc)
    SELECT 
        product.value('(SKU)[1]', 'int'),
        product.value('(Desc)[1]', 'varchar(30)')
    FROM @InputXML.nodes('Products/Product') AS X(product)
```

Comment: From 8 hours to 2 seconds, for a 5MB XML file.
Thank you sir!

Comment: Many thanks - for me also a multi-hour query.... never let it finish ... completed adding 30k rows in a few saeconds!

Comment: 18k rows in less than a second, ty!

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @xml table (x xml)
--
insert @xml
select x
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\temp\Products.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)

INSERT INTO dbo.Products (sku, product_desc)
SELECT
    RESULT.sku, RESULT.product_desc
FROM @xml
cross apply (
   select sku = z.value('SKU[1]', 'int'), 
          product_desc = z.value('Desc[1]','varchar(30)') 
   from x.nodes('Products/Product') Z1(z)
) RESULT
```

13000 records in 2 seconds
SQL Server 2008 R2. Database Compability 100

And also, try  Database Compability 90